# creating an image in matlab of 9 small white circles in a large black square

Tags: image, matlab, geometry

Im looking to create an image in Matlab of a large black rectangle with 9 small circles arranged as a a 3x3 array aligned in the centre of the rectangle, i.e. the centre circle will have its midpoint in the centre of the square.

I need the circles evenly spaced apart with some distance between each circle and between the outer circles and the border of the rectangle (think of a square piece of paper with 9 holes placed in it by stabbing it with a pen). I need this so that i can see how image convolution using a 2D gaussian will distort this image.

However I’m relatively new to Matlab and have been trying to create this image. I have successfully made a black/white square and a white circle in a black square which takes up most of the square itself but I cant seem to make a small white circle in any desired location in a black square let alone multiple small circles in a specific alignment.

---

This is what I have used to create the black square with a large circle:

```
X = ones([100,1])*([-50:49]);
Y = ([-50:49]')*(ones([1,100]));
Z = (X.^2)+(Y.^2);
image = zeros([100 100]);
image(find(Z<=50^2)) = 1;
imshow(image)
```

Comment: Hey, do you know what paragraphs are and to what purpose they serve? Its quite hard to even try to read what you wrote…

Comment: also would be helpful if you include an illustration, maybe even one drawn by hand in Paint or something..

Comment: Please give more details on what you have tried and what your specific problems where.

Comment: Sorry about the paragraphs. Typed this in a hurry.

This is what I have used to create the black square with a large circle:

>> X = ones([100,1])*([-50:49]);
>> Y = ([-50:49]')*(ones([1,100]));
>> Z = (X.^2)+(Y.^2);
>> image = zeros([100 100]);
>> image(find(Z<=50^2)) = 1;
>> imshow(image)

Comment: I tired increasing the size of the final image array (image = zeros([200 200]) but this induces more circles squashed into the left hand side of the square. I kind of understand what its doing, since the find <=50^ applies to the 100x100 array and . I thought what could be done is to get the matrix i have (image) and embed copies of this into a larger matrix in positions corresponding to the array I want but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: It says I cannot upload an image without a reputation of at least 10 is there anyway to get around this? If anyone wants to drop me their email I can send a paint picture of what I want.

Again sorry if things seem convoluted or I am not explaining myself well enough I'm new to the whole forum based questioning for things like this

Comment: @SeanJamesJamieson: you could upload to any image hosting site and post the link here. btw when you need to post any code you have, edit your question and post it there instead of a comment, that way it is properly displayed/formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, try this:

```
% size of each small box. Final image will be 3Nx3N
N = 100;

% create a circle mask
t = linspace(0,2*pi,50);   % approximated by 100 lines
r = (N-10)/2;              % circles will be separated by a 10 pixels border
circle = poly2mask(r*cos(t)+N/2+0.5, r*sin(t)+N/2+0.5, N, N);

% replicate to build image
img = repmat(circle, 3,3);
subplot(121), imshow(img)

% after applying Gaussian filter
h = fspecial('gaussian', [15 15], 2.5);
img2 = imfilter(im2double(img), h);
subplot(122), imshow(img2)
```

[image]